# Set the pixel location of a button in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to put a button on a specific pixel location on the screen of my application. I've looked up how to do it but all of the answers that I found were using either .place(), .grid() or pack(side = '__'); The problem that I found when using those two is that they calculate the new location relative to the location of another widget. There are two solutions that I know will be viable to me:

1. Create a 1pixel X 1pixel widget for which I can base all of the other locations on.
2. Use of some method to put the widget at that location

I would also be glad to hear of any other ways to achieve the desired action.
[I'm using python 3.4.4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to "set the pixel location of a button" is to use `place`. In your question you say that it doesn't work because the location is relative to another widget. This is true, but if you want an absolute position within the window, make the widget a child of the root window.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("150x150")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, background="blue")
f2 = tk.Frame(root, background="pink")

f1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
f2.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

button = tk.Button(root, text="click me!")
button.place(x=10, y=10, in_=root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if I was putting the button on a frame, would it be button.place(x=coordinate, y=coordinate, in_=frameName)?

Comment: @AllanLago: yes, you can do that, with some restrictions. From the official documentation: _"Master must either be window's parent or a descendant of window's parent."_